# QML items are not rendered

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

Interesting problem with QML. When I create a default Qt Quick application and run it, I get a black screen. Window and other items are not rendered at all. But when I minimize it and return it to previous state again, then items are rendered. So does anyone know about this kind of problem?
[Before minimizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzBLm.png)
[After minimizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd2ll.png)

In a very similar case (for another user), the window was being created, but none of the items were being rendered. In this case the window was completely blank (white) instead of black.
The system was a Windows 10 with Qt 5.15. This issue was not appearing on non-Windows system.
(The solution was related to OpenGL. See details below.)

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        id: test
        width: 300
        height: 200
        color: "red"
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 4
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        width: test.width / 2
        height: test.height / 2
        color: "red"
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 4
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height / 2
            radius: width * 0.5
            //x: 200
            //y: 200
            color: "green"
            border.color: "darkgreen"
            border.width: 4
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me as expected(Windows 8 / Qt 5.6). Probably that's a graphics card or VM/OpenGL problem.

Comment: From my experience with problematic graphic cards and Qt Quick I can suggest testing the app with this or similar flags: `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);`. Set it in C++ before loading QML.

Answer (score 3):

Today I have found a bug that may be what you experience. If I have enabled High Contrast in Windows then the application is not refreshing at all. I need to minimize it and reopen to see changes. Try disabling High Contrast if you have it enabled.

---

**Update:**

For some people, simply adding this line to the `main.cpp` of the project worked like a charm:

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

Another user reported that the issue was observed only on Windows 10 systems (Virtual Machines) with Qt 5.15. It didn't appear when the same code was tested on an Ubuntu 20.04 system with same configuration.